# Should i go to gym i'm 15

Tags: weightlifting, diet, gym

I'm 15 soon turning 16 and i have started going to gym about a week ago and i am regular but the question is should i continue? if yes, then what would be most appropriate for me to do in gym like weightlifting, bench-press/push-ups or walking/cycling etc. Please reply properly.
I'm 5'11" also i am thin 54 kg and i am an Indian. Also i will really like it if you could give me the answer to the diet i should take.

Comment: Don't ask three questions in one place, especially not if they have been asked and answered before on this site. And please provide more information alongside your question. If you want to know, if you should continue to go to the gym, you should tell us why you want to stop.

Comment: Are you just asking if its appropriate for you to lift weights if you're 15/16?  The answer is likely to be "yes", unless you have any existing medical problems or injuries, you're just at the age where most people (especially males) respond very well to weight training.  As for what to do, this question/answer has a basic starting point:  http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: The questions you're asking are very good ones, but they've been asked before, and covered in various posts.  People might be voting to close your question because its a little redundant.  If you have some specific reason why you think the existing questions about beginner weight lifting wouldn't apply to you, feel free to edit your question.  :)

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11522/what-are-the-health-risks-for-children-under-18-of-going-to-a-gym/11542#11542) for safety concerns of youth in gyms. Please see [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836) for building muscle and diet program for thin people

Comment: Thanks guys sorry i am new i didn't do any research on this website anyway i am gonna continue as @DavidR said its a "Yes" and also thanks to Moses

Comment: How about you read those other questions and then edit this question is you still have a question? If not, then we just close this one and you ask a new one if you end up having a new questions down the road

Comment: Yes you can close this question the answer is given. Thanks